# Monitor Being Signaled To Turn On Randomly

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, display, multiple-monitors

I have a system with Windows 8.1 on it that has had an annoying issue for a few months now. The system is setup to always be on while the monitors are set to timeout and turn off after a minute of not being used. However, every 10 minutes or so (it's completely random on the time), the monitors will turn back on. Nothing is going on on the system. No input was given from any input device.

The system is not going to sleep at all as it is setup to never sleep/hibernate, just simply turn off the monitors after a minute.

This happens every time the system is on, no matter what. Fresh reboot and it will start happening immediately after the screens turn off the first time.

Some info on the system:

- Windows 8.1
- Used as a development machine.
- Two monitors are connected. (1xHDMI, 1xDVI)
- Intel Core i7 4790K
- 16gigs G.Skill RAM
- Nvidia Geforce 970

Nothing is networked to this system (it is connected to the houses network but it is not sharing anything). No wireless connections are on this system either, just a single hardline with a static IP from the router.

The monitors will kick on at random within 5-10 mins of turning off. Will sit there for the minute or so and timeout again and turn off. This will repeat all day/night until the system is in use or turned off entirely.

Comment: Considering that graphics card, do you have Steam installed? Occasionally, they will have flash objects on their store page, which can occasionally keep the screens awake/wake them up.

Comment: I do, I will kill Steam for the night and see if that has any effect. Thanks for the suggestion.